# Angular 2 Interface

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to work with interfaces in Angular 2.
I've created a interface and a component.

Interface:

```
export interface Items {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    message: string;
    done: boolean;
}
```

Component:

```
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {
    currentItem: string;
    todos: any;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.currentItem = (localStorage.getItem('currentItem')!==null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentItem')) : [  ];
        this.todos = this.currentItem;
    }

    addTodo(item: Items) {
        this.todos.push({
            id: item.id,
            title: item.title,
            message: item.message,
            done: false
        });

        item.title = '';
        item.message = '';
        localStorage.setItem('currentItem', JSON.stringify(this.todos));
        console.log('retorno: ' + this.todos.title + ' titulo: ' + item.title);

        this.router.navigate(['./list']);
    }

   ngOnInit() {}

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <form (submit)="addTodo()">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Id:</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="id" class="textfield form-control" name="id">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Titulo:</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="title" class="textfield form-control" name="title">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Mensagem:</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="message" class="textfield form-control" name="message">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have an error: `EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a few things going wrong here.

The error is probably being caused by the fact that you're calling the `addTodo` function without an argument or an argument that is `undefined`. That's what causes the error you're describing.

Another possible problem may be that you have no class implementing the interface. Although this is not strictly necessary, it can help you make your code leverage the type safety of TypeScript better thereby helping you prevent errors.

**Update**: In your code update, you indeed call `addTodo` without a parameter, which causes it to be undefined in your function.

There are a few ways you can solve this, but I'll show you one. In your component, you can add the properties `id`, `title`, `message` (note that it might be better to place them in an object or rename them to keep things clear; this is just a minimal example). You can then use these properties to add your todo. So, instead of using `item.id`, `item.title`, and `item.message` you would use `this.id`, `this.title`, and `this.message`. These match the fields that you are referring to with your `ngModel` binding in the HTML template you provided.

Comment: Thank you! it works, doing it in this way I don't need the interface

Comment: True, this way you don't need the interface. It might be a bit more clean though to use an interface/object to store the data instead of directly putting the fields in your component. However, both ways work of course.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'll try to do it using interface, just for learn